# Cannot find name 'Component' - Angular 2 TypeScript error2304

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm new in Angular2 and TypeScript. When I try some examples like this bellow

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  template: `
    {{ value }}
    <button (click)="increase()">Increase</button>
    <button (click)="decrease()">Decrease</button>
  `
  })
  class Counter {
    value: number;

    constructor() {
    this.value = 1;
    }

    increase() {
    this.value = this.value + 1;
    }

    decrease() {
    this.value = this.value - 1;
    }
}
```

I face "**Cannot find name 'Component'**" error on compile.

What's the problem? 
What should I do?

Comment: have you imported the Component decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import things in TS, It doesn't know what that decorator is otherwise, but within angular you can provide it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Also make sure you export your class so you can import it elsewhere.

```
export class Counter
```